# GLKTextureLoader loads nothing, with no errors

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es-2.0, glkit

This code logs that the UIImage has a width, but the loaded texture has 0 width:

```
       NSDictionary * options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES],
                                  GLKTextureLoaderOriginBottomLeft,
                                  nil];

        NSError * error;

        UIImage * iu = [UIImage imageNamed:fileName];
        CGImageRef cg=iu.CGImage;

        NSLog(@"image size width: %f", iu.size.width);

        self.textureInfo= [GLKTextureLoader textureWithCGImage:cg options:options error:&error];
        if (self.textureInfo == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Error loading file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            return nil;
        }            

        NSLog(@"texture width: %f", self.textureInfo.width);
```

If that last log line shows `0` what am I doing wrong? There is no error logged.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the logging, not the texture loading. It is an `int`:

`NSLog(@"texture width: %i", self.textureInfo.width);`